# Correct use of "consulting"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I'm really not sure how to correctly use consulting.

For example:

> The business offers consulting for(?) programming.
>
> Their employees consult their customers for(?) programming.

In sentences like these, I'm not certain what words to use.

Is **for**, the correct term? Or is it rather consult **with**?

*edit*: Maybe I'm using the completely wrong term. Consulting in terms of giving advice, is what I meant.

*edit2*: [According to this source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/consult), it should be used like this:

> **Consult somebody about/on something**:
>
> I expect to be consulted about major issues.

---

So the initial statements would be:

> The business offers consulting **about** programming.
>
> Their employees consult their customers **about** programming.

Is that correct?

Comment: What are you trying to get your example sentences to say?

Comment: '...offers consultation on...'

Comment: @Lawrence Two example sentences, in the first the action is done by the business, in the second the action is done by a person. I just wanted to give different examples.

Comment: @marcellothearcane So you would suggest the example would be correct like this: The business offers consulting on programming. ?

Comment: Here's the [dictionary entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consulting) for *consulting* in the business sense. It contains lots of examples.

Comment: @SaAtomic yes, something like that...